# HYperledger Fabric Building First Network

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-chaincode, ibm-blockchain

While trying to build the first network with Windows this error keeps coming!

Error: Failed to get client TLS config: Failed to read 'C:\c\Users\User\fabric-samples\test-network\organizations\peerOrganizations\org1.example.com\c\Users\User\fabric-samples\test-network\organizations\fabric-ca\org1\tls-cert.pem': open C:\c\Users\User\fabric-samples\test-network\organizations\peerOrganizations\org1.example.com\c\Users\User\fabric-samples\test-network\organizations\fabric-ca\org1\tls-cert.pem: The system cannot find the path specified.
organizations/fabric-ca/registerEnroll.sh: line 26: /c/Users/User/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp/config.yaml: No such file or directory

[Error reading configuration: Unsupported Config Type ""
2021-09-12 20:49:43.710 +06 [common.tools.configtxgen] func1 -> ERRO 003 Could not find configtx.yaml. Please make sure that FABRIC_CFG_PATH or -configPath is set to a path which contains configtx.yaml

- res=1
  Failed to generate orderer genesis block...
  ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iU66j.png)

Comment: can anyone help with FABRIC_CFG_PATH?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue few hours ago and I followed the suggestion given in the error message, I got passed the issue but hit another issue while I was trying to run ./network.sh createChannel command so I had to opt for using WSL.

> Please make sure that FABRIC_CFG_PATH

The path was already set correctly in the network.sh file so there is no need to do anything with the first suggestion.

> or -configPath is set to a path which contains configtx.yaml

I followed the second suggestion by adding `-configPath ./configtx` to the command in the **createConsortium()** method in the network.sh file. The command looks like the below code after but like I said I could not get it to work so I had to do it on WSL

```
configtxgen -configPath ./configtx -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -channelID system-channel -outputBlock ./system-genesis-block/genesis.block
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `FABRIC_CFG_PATH` to the path of `configtx.yaml`.

Comment: You might want to add an explanation as to why this needs to be done.